# My tree branches have holes at the tips

Tags: sapling-addon

[image]

I'm using the Sampling generator and has you can see, for some reason, the little branches have these holes at the tips, why is that? And how can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the *Minimum Radius* property under *Branch Radius* category to control the branch tip diameter while crating a new sapling tree.

You can also tick the option *Close Tip* as mentioned by Akados in the comments.

[image]

If you already created one then enter edit mode and select all branch tips and adjust their size with the Bezier *Curve Radius* property from the *Properties Shelf* <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. You may want to turn on *Proportional Editing*

To easily select all tips you may use the *Select Grouped* operator with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and try to select by *Radius*.

[image]

Comment: You could also check 'Close Tip'.

Comment: Indeed, good tip, I'll add it to the answer. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Thank you for this. I somehow missed those options, but I do find the sappling generator a bit confusing, due to all the many sliders and whatnot. :P

Answer (score -2):

First choose all vertices in *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill holes with faces.